# errors with static functions in python 2.7

Tags: class, static, python-2.7

I've a problem while using static functions in python.
I've a class with my static function

```
class CFileSystemOperations(object):
    ....
    ....
    def getRepositoryDirectory():
        ......
        return sRepositoryDirectory            
    getRepositoryDirectory = staticmethod(getRepositoryDirectory)
```

then I've another class with a function calling the static one, i try 2 solutions

```
class CMusicOrganizerView(object):
    ....
    def __init__(self):
        ....
        #first solution
        sGuessedRepositoryTextfield = CFileSystemOperations().getRepositoryDirectory()
        #second solution
        sGuessedRepositoryTextfield = CFileSystemOperations.getRepositoryDirectory()
```

here there is the error:

> sGuessedRepositoryTextfield = CFileSystemOperations().getRepositoryDirectory()
> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
>
> sGuessedRepositoryTextfield = CFileSystemOperations.getRepositoryDirectory()
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getRepositoryDirectory'
> ERROR: Module: musicOrganizer could not be imported (file: /..../musicOrganizer.py).

any ideas? thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You confused a module with the class contained within it. Use

```
CFileSystemOperations.CFileSystemOperations().getRepositoryDirectory()
```

(and give your modules better names; they do not *have* to match the contained class names like you do in Java).

Comment: Just a question, name of the files (the modules) in a way they should represent the classes they contain. So I've thought to name them in the same way. Modules should be name shortly? (Asking from a convention point of view)

Comment: See [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) for naming conventions.